# rspec change expectation fails when using active record pessimistic locking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pessimistic-locking

I have a `Rails 4.2.0` method that uses pessimistic locking to change a counter

```
class Foo < < ActiveRecord::Base
  def bump!
    transaction do
      lock!
      parent.lock!

      lock.counter += 1
      parent.counter += 1

      save!
      parent.save!
    end
  end
end
```

I am using `Rspec 3.1` to test it like so

```
expect{foo.bump!}.to change(foo, :counter).by(1)
expect{foo.bump!}.to change(foo.parent, :counter).by(1)
```

The first `change(foo, :counter)` test passes but the second `change(foo.parent, :counter)` fails unless I comment out both `lock!` and `parent.lock!`

If I rewrite the failing test like this, it passes

```
prev_counter = foo.parent.counter
foo.bump!
expect(foo.parent.counter).to eq prev_counter + 1
```

Why doesn't it work with `expect{...}.to change`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the instance of `foo.parent` in your RSpec test is not the same instance of `parent` that your `Foo#bump!` method is modifying, because calling `parent.lock!` [reloads the parent association to get the lock](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) and thus you modify a different instance than [rspec has bound its own lambda to](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/change.rb#L305). The simplest fix is to use the `change { }` syntax which doesn't bind the receiver instance to `foo.parent` but instead just to `foo`, which doesn't change, like so:

```
expect{foo.bump!}.to change{foo.counter}.by(1)
expect{foo.bump!}.to change{foo.parent.counter}.by(1)
```

This fix worked locally for me.